# Формирование и получение xml  на ruby

Tags: xml, ruby, ruby-on-rails

какая конструкция обеспечивает отправку xml на некоторый порт?

```
def view
    z1 = Net::HTTP.get('localhost', '/avtm/view.xml',"3000"); 
    xmls = Document.new(z1)
    @n = XPath.match(xmls, "//n").map {|x| x.text}
  end
```

это предполагаемый код получения результата. 
причем одна из страниц должна передавать результат, а другая его считывать.
Это правильно формирующаяся, но не отправляющаяся страница:

```
def view()
 b=params[:b].to_i
 @z=avtomorfushka(b).size #собственная функция рассчетов
 @zz=avtomorfushka(b)

respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @zz } 
            format.xml { render xml: @zz } 
    end 
end
```

Comment: Вы хотите сгенерировать xml и отправить результат HTTP-запросом на какой-то произвольный адрес?

Comment: > причем одна из страниц должна передавать результат, а другая его считывать

Нет такого понятия, есть HTTP-запросы (POST, GET, ...). Опишите что вы хотите получить (в терминах запросов).

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит приглядеться к [Фарадею](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).